Garbled screen when using Cygwin64 XWin
I am using Cygwin64 the latest version, the shell part works fine, but when I try to start a local X11 session, the screen is garbled, this is the case when using xwin and xwin -rootless when I use xwin -multiwindow its fine, no garbled output.
Example:

I have tried with twm, ctwm and mwm, its the same no matter what, garbled output, like the example above. I have also tried different versions of X11, upgrading, downgrading, uninstalling Cygwin completely, nothing seems to help. I have other computers where Cygwin just works, without any problems. Intel HD Graphics 4000, latest driver from Intel.
Any advice?
